# Why does this function exist formally?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

Let $X$ be a set and $x_1,...,x_n \in X$. I want to prove formally that there exists a function $f:\{1,...,n\} \to \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ that maps $1$ to $x_1$, $2$ to $x_2$,..., $n$ to $x_n$. Informally this can be done by using the "$...$" notation:

$$f:=\{(1,x_1)\} \cup ... \cup \{(n,x_n)\} \subseteq X \times \mathbb{N}.$$ However, when trying to infer such an existence from the ZFC axioms, I wouldn't know how to do it without using the informal dot notation. Is there a way to do this? Furthermore, would I need to begin the statement with "let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X$ be a set (...)"? If the variables $x_1,...,x_n$ would behave like function symbols and one would be allowed to write something like $$f:=\{(i,x_i) \ : \ i \in \mathbb{N} \wedge i \leq n \}$$ then this would do the job, but I don't think this is allowed since these are variables and not function symbols.

Comment: First and foremost: $x_1,\cdots, x_n\in X$ is a shorthand notation to refer to a function $x_\bullet:\{j\in \Bbb N\,:\, 1\le j\le n\}\to X$ without bothering with the fact that it's a function. Therefore, what you're caliming is *false*, because there is no indication that $x_\bullet$ is injective.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I thought that this is the case at first, but I don't think this is correct. As far as I know formal languages allow finitely indexed variables even without having a notion of a mathematical function.

Comment: You are still not addressing the fact that you're trying to prove a false theorem. As for the last comment: yes, but you have to write them all down.

Comment: @user103178981 assume very specific situation, say $X = \{42\}$, $n = 2$, $x_1 = x_2 = 42$. Can you write your $f$ for such case?

Comment: For instance: if you want to say that for all $x_1,\cdots, x_n\in X$ there is a subset of $X$ that contains exactly the $x_i$-s, in ZFC you are trying to say that $$\forall n,\forall x_\bullet:\{s\in \Bbb N\,:\, 1\le s\le n\}\to X,\exists G\subseteq X,\forall y(y\in G\leftrightarrow \exists j, y=x_j)$$ [continues]

Comment: On the other hand, if I call $Q_n$ and $P_{n,k}$ the well-formed formulae defined recursively as $$Q_1\equiv [y=x_1]\\ Q_{n+1}\equiv [Q_1\lor y=x_{n+1}]\\ P_{0,k}\equiv [\exists G\subseteq X,\forall y(y\in G\leftrightarrow Q_k)]\\ P_{n+1,k}\equiv [\forall x_{n+1}\in X,(P_{n,k})]$$ then in some theory that allows me to speak of ZFC and of theorems of ZFC I can prove that, for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $[\forall X, P_{n,n}]$ is a theorem of ZFC (and of ZF without infinity and many other axioms, for that matter).